# How to summon an NPC?

Tags: dark-souls-2

I play offline and don't currently have an Xbox Live subscription.

I know this means I cannot summon other players, but can I still summon NPCs?

I am currently at the fight of the 3 sentinels and I thought you could summon an NPC to help with them. I am human but when I pull out the white sign soapstone (just before the fight), it is greyed out/disabled.

Am I missing a step?

Comment: You need to find a sign on the ground, if any, in order to summon an npc. The white soapstone is meant to write down on the ground your sign so that you can be summoned by others.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to find the NPC's summoning sign, which should be somewhere on the ground nearby (assuming there is an NPC summon available there). Once you find the sign, you can activate it to summon the NPC in question. The sign should appear as long as you're in human form.

White sign soapstone is the item you use to offer yourself for being summoned to other people's worlds, and hence, it is disabled when offline.

Comment: Gotcha, do you happen to know if there are any circumstances that cause the NPC summon sign to show up/ not show up?

Comment: @JDIsaacks As long as you're in human form, it should appear.

Comment: By the way, I found out that because I was in a certain covenant, the one up the hill in Majula, I think it's called the warriors covenant or something. It makes you unable to summon. I dropped it, then I could summon, but after dropping it I didn't need to because the boss was much easier.

Answer (score 1):

You need to be in human form, for some summons find NPC first, and then do not be in the covenant from majula- covenant of champions or something like that. It makes your game harder and makes you unable to summon.